# Xbox 360 fails to sync with my monitor

Tags: monitor, xbox-360

I have connected my xbox 360 to my computer monitor so i can easily switch between without having to use different monitors. Thing is that my monitor is HD and the xbox interface is not HD. In fact, it is so blury and pixelated that it's impossible to see enemies comming from far. It's not game related, this blur comes as soon as i boot up the xbox and enter the menu.
I'm not sure if this has to do about whether i'm using HDMI or RGB or anything else (I use AV2 by the way).
I switched from AV1 to AV2 because i noticed a slight difference, but still looks bad.
So i tried adjusting the settings on xbox, and PAL 50 Hz seems to be fixing the problem (Default was PAL 60 Hz for some reason) but NONE of my games support 50 Hz, so it prompts me to change it back to 60 Hz.
So what the hell, is there any way to escape this hell?

P.S: My xbox and games are both using PAL format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Xbox interface is not HD, that means you're not using HDMI.

As you mentioned, you are using AV2 as your TV input, which means that you are using a regular composite (RGB) cable, not HDMI. Most of the time, a composite cannot transmit a high-definition signal; it can only transmit regular PAL.

You need to change out your A/V output to an HDMI cable. This should resolve all of your blurriness problems.

Comment: My monitor doesn't have any hdmi ports -.-

Answer (score 0):

By saying your xbox interface isn't HD you've already solved your problem! What model of the xbox do you own? If its an older generation model then you should upgrade to a newer model that supports HDMI ports. Consoles are a pretty as is type of device and in order to keep up to date with graphics they release new models while scrapping old ones. Test a friend's xbox on your monitor to confirm the issue is with the old xbox and not your monitor. Use different cables to also rule out any issues that might arise with faulty cabling.